# display only file name from the image path

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing image files into a folder and storing into database with full file path along with file name.ie..it stores as http://someurl.com/app-name/files/store/K1_M.pdf.

I'm displaying the database records into a table and thus it shows the file field(which stores full path of the file in db) with full path.but, here i want to display only file name instead of file path without disturbing the file path stored in database.

below is the code i used to display table data

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from new where " . $where . " limit $offset,$rows");
```

i know that we can use

`end(explode('/',$str))`

but don't know how to include in my code..

plz help in resolving..thanks

Comment: `$name`= pathinfo(`$str`, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMNNAME,'\\/',-1) AS filename
 FROM TABLENAME LIMIT $offset,$rows");
```

Replace COLUMNNAME with name of your database field, TABLENAME with your database table name.

Comment: what need to be given in place of filename?

Comment: filename is the output, filename from complete path.                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs); then echo $row['filename'];

Comment: i tried..but it is not displaying any values in the table

Comment: There is a change in SUBSTRING_INDEX(), check it